# Absolute positioned element moves when size of other element changes

Tags: html, css

I've created this jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/k5mzg46k/17/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" id="btn1">
    <p id="text">
        LOL LOL
    </p>
    <input type="button" class="btn2">
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick =

function run() {
    var element = document.getElementById("text");
  element.innerHTML = "";
}
```

CSS:

```
#text {
        margin: 0 auto;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#btn1{
  height: 47px;
  width: 47px;
}

.btn2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

So I have a div container with a button on top, some text below and a button at the bottom. I need the button at the bottom to stay there no matter what, so I tried to use absolute positioning. However, as the first button is pressed, the text in the middle is removed which makes the bottom button move up.

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: your absolute positioning is not really positioning, since you didn't specify a top or bottom value.  Are any of the elements (the .container or the .btn1 + p) fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can change your JavaScript to just hide your element:

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick =

function run() {
  var element = document.getElementById("text");
  element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Or if you have to delete the element, you can put the button out of the div and the display: absolute will work (also change button's left and right):

```html
<div class="container">
<input type="button" id="btn1">
<p id="text">
LOL LOL
</p>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn2">
```